# iOS: Issues with sending unicode text on server

Tags: ipad, unicode, utf-8, ios5.1, unicode-string

I have come across really frustrating issue related to Unicode text and I am not able to do anything more to fix it. I am using following code to store English and Japanese texts on server from iPad.

```
    __block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    request.defaultResponseEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"charset=UTF-8;"];

    NSData *data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request appendPostData:data];
```

**The weird thing is English text(in the same texts) gets stored fine on server but not Japanese.** They get converted into some garbage text. For example When I UTF8 encode to " This is test フロントドアに表示されたアメックスのステッカーはありますか" text, it stored as "This is test ãƒ•ãƒ­ãƒ³ãƒˆãƒ‰ã‚¢ã«è¡¨ç¤ºã•ã‚ŒãŸã‚¢ãƒ¡ãƒƒã‚¯ã‚¹ã®ã‚¹ãƒ†ãƒƒã‚«ãƒ¼ã¯ã‚ã‚Šã¾ã™ã‹ï¼Ÿ".

Could anyone please point me what's going wrong here? Thanks.

[EDIT]

From [ASIHTTPRequest documen](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)t,

```
Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest

To send POST data in a manner compatible with web page forms, use the included. 
ASIFormDataRequest subclass. ***Data is posted in ‘application/x-www-form-urlencoded’ 
format, or ‘multipart/form-data’ format when uploading binary data*** or files. Data in 
files is read as needed from disk, so POSTing large files is OK, as long as your 
web server is setup to handle them.
```

So I converted my code to use ASIHTTPRequest instead of ASIFormDataRequest but still no luck!

```
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"charset=UTF-8;"];

    NSData *data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request appendPostData:data];
```

Comment: How are you storing the text on the server? Have you checked wether the server received the text in `UTF8`?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: What does your server consist of, how is it storing it, how are you checking the result?

Comment: Server does store whatever I send. Before converting text to UTF8, I print the text which comes fine as I said. I convert text(mix of english and japanese) to UTF8 and send to server. When I get back the same text from the server it comes wrong! I have server side functionality as well that allow to save same text and that works fine! So when I update text from server it self, iPad gets the correct japanese characters but when iPad updates these texts, it starts messing around! Server is also using UTF8 encoding so not sure what's going wrong!

Comment: The problem could be anywhere between encoding the data in iOS, receiving and storing it on the server, returning it from the server and receiving it on iOS. At which of these points are you starting to see garbage exactly?

Comment: Hi @deceze server side things are absolutely fine. iPad receives unicodes absolutely fine as available on server. The problem start when iPad post back the unicode data. In short, iPad doesn't seem to encode japanese characters correctly or server is not able to recognise that iPad sent UTF8 data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following worked! You have to have value = "text/json; charset=utf-8" for content-type. Just setting charset won't work!!

```
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"post"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"content-type" value:@"text/json; charset=utf-8"];
```